# android + google map API

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, maps, google-maps-api-2

I created a map in the application through Google Maps Android API v2. And the map works in the emulator. But when download applications from the Play Market map does not work, does not work even if you send APK in USB to your smartphone.  because of what it can be? And how to fix it?

Comment: you need to add you production certificate to that key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using debug key for your map.
There are two keys: for debug mode and release mode.
If you want your map appears after publishing to Google Play you must provide release key for the map.
Please check below link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en